# Question about the potential energy of a charge

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, batteries

If I place a book on a shelf in a gravitational field, the book will of course continuously exert a force on the bookshelf.

If I place a small charge above a barrier in an electrostatic field emanating below the barrier, will the charge exert a continuous force on the barrier?

Macroscopic intuition suggests yes, since, for example, if I rub a balloon on my hair, and then slowly pull the balloon away, the attraction is strong enough to cause my hair to push the surrounding air out of the way, allowing my hair to stand up.

Similarly, is there a force associated with the potential difference in a battery?

Comment: What do you mean by "barrier"? If it's electrically charged, it will feel the Coulomb force and if not then not, as usual. As for the battery - the difference in electric potential can lead to forces, but it's not as simple as having "a" force associated with a given potential difference.

Comment: To make it more concrete, let's say the barrier is non-conductive rubber. If the charge is sitting on top of the rubber, and the field is below the rubber, will the charge exert a force on the rubber barrier? My intuition is yes. So my follow up question is, does a battery have internal forces at work because of similar attractions due to differences in potential.

Comment: Why would the rubber feel the charge? It will feel the weight of the charge, but that has nothing to do with the quantity of the electric charge. The rubber is neutral so it won't feel any electric force from the electric charge. (To a first approximation. In practice, there would be a tiny bit of polarization and hence some force felt.)

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to understand your issue now. You are asking how the charged mass is repelled by the Normal force. Yes, if you want to get down to that level of description, then the charge will exert a force on the rubber as it gets squeezed by gravity towards a few electrons in the rubber's outer surface. It will get squeezed-in until the repulsing by the rubber atoms will offset the gravity force on the charged mass, i.e. until the Normal force equals the charged mass's weight. I still don't get what any of this has to do with a battery.

Comment: No, I'm asking whether the electrostatic field will cause the charge to exert a force above that which is due to gravity. So if the rubber is horizontal, and the charge is to the right, and the filed to the left, will the charge exert a force on the rubber barrier?

Comment: Ignoring polarisation, the only force the electrostatic field causes directly is the electric force on the charged mass. Assuming said charge is positive, in your setup this is a force to the left. The charged mass will thus be pushed against the rubber barrier, and thus indirectly the electrostatic field will also cause the mass (but not the charge) to exert a force on the rubber barrier. Polarization will cause positive surface charge on the left side of the rubber barrier, and a negative one on the right edge, attracting the charged mass and increasing the effect slightly.